# How to create a new varaible in R from levels of other varaibles

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with three variables. The levels of each never repeat themselves, in fact they are levels of ONE variable. I need to recreate this variable. How do I do it in R?

The dataframe look likes this:

```
Var1: NA NA NA A NA
Var2: NA NA B NA NA
Var3: C C NA NA C
```

I want to have a single variable out of these three so it would look like this:

```
Final Var: C C B A C
```

Comment: This is clearly an R programming question & has a reproducible example. This should be fine on [SO]. I'm going to migrate it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let your data frame be called `dat`, and has only the variables listed (no other variables that you don't want included, all variables have the same type, viz., character).  Then you can coerce the data frame to a matrix and to a vector, and drop the `NA`s:

```
> dat
    V1   V2   V3
1 <NA> <NA>    C
2 <NA> <NA>    C
3 <NA>    B <NA>
4    A <NA> <NA>

> final <- as.vector(as.matrix(dat))
> final <- final[!is.na(final)]
> final
[1] "A" "B" "C" "C"
```

Comment: Alternatively, the single command `dat[!is.na(dat)]` does everything at once (+1).

Answer (score 0):

You would first need to replace NA with empty cells like so

```
df[is.na(df)] <- " "
```

And then use the [paste function](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/paste.html) to concatenate the variables. 
Cheers

Comment: Thank you! that's great